# What do you do when a migration won't migrate down?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I decided not to use the gem ['acts_as_taggable_on'](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on) but I'm having trouble undoing the migrations for some reason.  There are 5:

```
   ** ^ more migrations ^ **
   up     20151018064454  Acts as taggable on migration.acts as taggable on engine
   up     20151018064455  Add missing unique indices.acts as taggable on engine
   up     20151018064456  Add taggings counter cache to tags.acts as taggable on engine
  down    20151018064457  Add missing taggable index.acts as taggable on engine
  down    20151018064458  Change collation for tag names.acts as taggable on engine
  ** v more migrations v **
```

When I run `rake db:migrate:down VERSION=20151018064456` I get errors:

> PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "taggings_count" of relation "tags" does not exist
>
> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "taggings_count" of relation "tags" does not exist
>   : ALTER TABLE "tags" DROP "taggings_count"
>
> PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "taggings_count" of relation
>   "tags" does not exist

I'm running them one at a time from latest to earliest.  If these don't run, what should I do?

Comment: Showing us the failing migration might ..uhhhm.. help to diagnose.

Comment: def self.down
    remove_column :tags, :taggings_count
  end

Comment: If your DB is on developement, try `rake db:migrate:reset` which will rollback all migrations and start migrating from the beginning, so that you have a clean DB without any data!

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

`rake db:rollback` will get you back one step

then

```
rake db:rollback STEP=n
```

Will roll you back `n` migrations where `n` is the number of recent migrations you want to rollback.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I need to start it from 20151018064458 and there are more migrations after.  Is rollback any different than down?

Comment: Hi, more or less: **db:migrate:down** rolls back one specific migration
**db:rollback** rolls back the last migration , generally you use rollback, since it clears tables and drop them if necessary, migrate:down , instead, could leave some garbage on your db, give them both a try though